# Deleting a VM in azure and its effect on websites

Tags: azure

I am new to azure. For one of my client a programmer has set up azure sites and VM. But now he is not with this client. Now the client wants to delete or shut down the VM because it would save his credits. I have found that there is nothing installed in VM for that client.

So my question is if I am going to delete or shutdown the VM by describing procedure then it can effect the existing sites or not. I cannot able to find any link between site and VM.

Can someone explain me that if there is any relation between web sites and virtual machine in azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Azure perspective there is no relation between an Azure Website (assuming you are referring to Azure Websites feature - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/web-sites/) and an Azure VM so you should be ok to shut down the VM.

However, you should be certain that the VM is not being used by the website.  Could there be a SQL server, file share, etc on that VM that the website is accessing?  You can shut down the VM and then make sure the website is still working.  If something goes wrong with the website then you will know that it was accessing the VM for some reason and then quickly restart the VM from the .VHD still in storage (just make sure you don't delete the VHD or attached disks when you shut down the VM).

Alternatively if you wanted to do some more investigation before shutting down the VM you could run netmon/wireshark on the VM for a couple days and make sure no traffic is coming to the VM from the website.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have shut down the VM and websites are still working.